# How to add Coverage for SonarQube?

Tags: c#, sonarqube, code-coverage, xunit

I have used xUnit test cases for my project. The sonar scan reflects the codesmells but not the coverage and unit tests. How to link xUnit related coverage with sonar so that the coverage gets reflected in the results?

[I have tried to link the unit test file but could not find a field related to xUnit tests but only NUnit and VSTest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh5Ix.png)

What should I do for the coverage to be reflected?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the NuGet package 'Coverlet.msbuild' to your test projects. This package will generate a coverage file which sonar can pick up and process.